# Spring boot swagger SocketIO create 1 'global' connection? Or connect & disconnect on every API call?

Tags: spring-boot, socket.io, jhipster

I have this code in RpiAlertResource.java

```
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;
...

@PostMapping("/nms-rpi-alertsMany")
    public String createNmsRpiAlertMany(@RequestBody NmsRpiAlert rpiAlert) throws URISyntaxException {

....

Socket socket;
try {
    socket = IO.socket("https://xxx.xxx.xx");
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            socket.emit("InsertAlert", alert.getId(), alert.getSentToZones() );

            socket.disconnect();
        }

    }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
        }
    });

    socket.connect();

} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So it opens and closes a socket connection every time the api is called.
Is working ok. But like this api is called a lot. Like twice a minute I was wondering if there is a better way to implement this connection?

Like a 'global' socket connection, that could reconnect again when it losses connection?

Where in a Springboot application do I set this connection?

Comment: You could do it in an `@Service` annotated class but between 1 and infinite number of connections, you could use a connection pool. Whatever you decide, consider running stress tests and profile CPU/memory consumption and error rate.

Comment: Thank @GaëlMarziou. Do you have any suggestions (links) where I can learn more about implementing a connection pool in a /@service annotated class?

Comment: No. But to clarify I suggest to use an existing connection pool like apache commons-pool2, however remember  that  I don't have experience with websockets. Anyway the most important advice I can give you is to stress test your app (with jmeter or gatling) before thinking about optimisations that could be premature.